# Optimal CUDA thread/block count for a function with no inputs (random sampling)

Tags: random, cuda, gpu, nvidia, montecarlo

There are a lot of questions about optimizing the number of threads and blocks in a CUDA function, but everything I've found is about matching them to the problem size.

I have a task with no problem size. My inputs are random numbers and my output is to be reduced to a single scalar. For simplicity, suppose that I'm computing π by throwing uniformly random points *x* ∊ (‒1, 1) and *y* ∊ (‒1, 1) to see how many fall within the unit circle. I'll need a random number generator and an output array as large as my total number of threads so that each thread can increment its count without atomics/contention. Then I'll need to sum the output array to get a single scalar.

I *think* the optimal way to do this is to use 1024 threads on exactly 1 block, since everything that I read says that an NVIDIA GPU can run no more than 1024 threads at a time. I don't see any advantage to stopping a thread and continuing the random number generation in the next block, and if the random number generator is stateful, it could be better to keep it running in a `for` loop within the thread, anyway.

Am I missing something? And why isn't this use-case more common (why don't I see more questions about it)? Monte Carlo's a thing...

---

**Edit:** empirically, it's optimized for larger number of blocks (mitigated by the fact that more random seeds are needed for those blocks). I did this test with Numba:

```py
import cupy as cp
import numba as nb

import numba.cuda
from numba.cuda.random import create_xoroshiro128p_states
from numba.cuda.random import xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32

@nb.cuda.jit
def run_gpu(states, out, num_times):
    i = nb.cuda.grid(1)
    for _ in range(num_times):
        if xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32(states, i) > 0.5:
            out[i] += 1

global_seed = [0]

def run(num_times_total, num_blocks):
    global_seed[0] += 1
    states = create_xoroshiro128p_states(1024 * num_blocks, seed=global_seed[0])
    out = cp.zeros(1024 * num_blocks, dtype=np.float32)
    run_gpu[num_blocks, 1024](states, out, num_times_total // num_blocks)
    return out.sum() / 1024 / num_times_total
```

The function only integrates the unit distribution from 0.5 to 1 (the result is approximately 0.5), but each `run` trades an increasing `num_blocks` for a decreasing `num_times` in the loop, such that the `num_times_total` is held constant (`4*1024**2`) in this test. The results (using `%timeit` and a GeForce RTX 3060) are

| `num_blocks` | time (ms) | only the kernel, no seed-generation or reduction (ms) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4210 | 4210 |
| 2 | 1880 | 1879 |
| 4 | 930 | 929 |
| 8 | 466 | 465 |
| 16 | 270 | 268 |
| 32 | 267 | 262 |
| 64 | 203 | 194 |
| 128 | 173 | 155 |
| 256 | 172 | 137 |
| 512 | 160 | 90 |
| 1024 | 174 | 34 |
| 2048 | 332 | 50 |
| 4096 | 610 | 48 |
| 8192 | 1220 | 90 |

So the optimum is not 1 block, but why? My second question above still stands: what am I missing? Why is it better to distribute the process over more blocks instead of running a `for` loop longer when the GPU can only run a maximum of 1024 threads at a time?

Comment: The 1024 limit is for each SM, [your 3060 has 28 of them](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-rtx-3060-12-gb.c3682). I.e. with a single block you are using at most one 28th of the 3060. Please read [CUDA C++ Programming Guide: Hardware Implementation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#hardware-implementation) and [CUDA C++ Best Practices Guide: Execution Configuration Optimizations](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#execution-configuration-optimizations)

Comment: Thanks; the Best Practices Guide is what I needed to see—I'll turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on @paleonix's answer from the comments, here's where I was wrong:

> everything that I read says that an NVIDIA GPU can run no more than 1024 threads at a time.

One *Streaming Multiprocessor (SM)* can do no more than 1024 (or maybe 2048) threads at a time, but a GPU has many SMs.

In [CUDA C++ Best Practices Guide: Execution Configuration Optimizations](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#execution-configuration-optimizations),

> Modern NVIDIA GPUs can support up to 2048 active threads concurrently per multiprocessor (see Features and Specifications of the CUDA C++ Programming Guide) On GPUs with 80 multiprocessors, this leads to more than 160,000 concurrently active threads.

This is an important point that I think is obscured by the information that I've been finding in web-searches. (Try a [Google search for "maximum number of cuda threads"](https://www.google.com/search?q=maximum+number+of+cuda+threads). It gives you a big "1024 threads" above the search results.) In retrospect, I recognize now that those are guides say "threads per block" and what they're trying to do is help users choose what integer to put in the block/thread configuration, not to answer to the question of how many total threads the GPU is capable of.

If you're using Python, you can get that value with CuPy:

```py
>>> import cupy as cp
>>> dev0_attrs = cp.cuda.Device(0).attributes
>>> dev0_attrs["MaxThreadsPerBlock"] * dev0_attrs["MultiProcessorCount"]
28672
```

(1024 × 28 for me). In my empirical test of distributing 4194304 (`4*1024**2`) random number generations among total threads and steps in a `for` loop, my GPU became fully saturated at 28672 total threads, which is `num_blocks ≈ 146` (`4*1024**2 / 28672`). In the table, the total time seems to level off around there, and it only gets worse for larger numbers of blocks because I have to generate random number states for them—that's what dominates at large numbers of blocks.

So it all makes sense. Thanks, @paleonix!

Comment: @JimPivarksi You might also want to try varying the block size while keeping the total number of threads constants. While it may not apply here, often smaller block sizes, say 256 threads per block, allow for better utilization of GPU resources due to effects of granularity of resource allocation inside the hardware.